# Translate JMS Queue XML config to Java config

Tags: spring-integration

In order to learn spring integration I've been attempting to create a simple, resilient log processor. I'm also wanting to stick with a java configuration approach.

I've been having a difficult time translating existing XML configuration, mostly due to being so new to spring in general.

In [a question on the spring forums](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/94764-file-channel-adapter-issues) Gary Russell presented a similar solution to this using a publish-subscribe + JMS model with a simple XML config.

I've been attempting to translate his suggestion into a Java config, but am stuck. Namely I'm not sure of the proper entities to use for the outbound-channel-adapter, service-activators or how to set the order of messages properly.

Here is Gary's XML config:

```
   <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="dispatcher" 
        directory="spool" 
        channel="fileChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="2000">
            <int:transactional/>
        </int:poller>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="fileChannel" />

    <int-file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="fileChannel" output-channel="dispatchChannel" />

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="dispatchChannel" />

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="dispatcherJms" channel="dispatchChannel" order="1"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        destination="dispatcher.queue" />

    <!-- If JMS Send was successful, remove the file (within the transaction)-->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="dispatchChannel" order="2" 
        output-channel="nullChannel" 
                    expression="headers.file_originalFile.delete()">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments below I've updated the java config.

However I'm still receiving errors and most likely am not understanding the flow and connections between the entities, but the original question has been answered.

```
@Bean
@Transactional
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "dispatchChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "2000"))
public MessageSource<?> dispatcher() {
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(sourceFilenamePattern));
    //filters.addFilter(persistentFilter());

    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    source.setDirectory(new File(sourceDirectory));
    source.setFilter(filters);

    return source;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel fileChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public PublishSubscribeChannel dispatchChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Autowired
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Autowired
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
@Order(1)
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "dispatchChannel")
public MessageHandler dispatcherJmsOutboundChannelAdapter(Message<File> message) {
    JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplate);
    handler.setDestinationName("dispatcher.queue");

    return handler;
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "dispatchChannel")
public void removeFile(Message<?> message) {
    //message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class).delete();
    log.info("delete");
}

@Bean
public JmsTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}
```

I'm using spring boot and several starter components, such as activemq. I've added the @Bean for JmsListenerContainerFactory and a @JmsListener, though I'm not sure those are truly necessary.

I couldn't get anything to run until adding @EnableJms to my configuration file as well as @Autowiring the jmstemplate and connectionfactory.

When running, the error I'm receiving now is:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.messaging.Message] found for dependency 
[org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>]: 
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="dispatchChannel" order="2" 
    output-channel="nullChannel" 
                expression="headers.file_originalFile.delete()">
```

is pretty simple in Java:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "dispatchChannel")
public void removeFile(Message<?> message) {
    message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class).delete();
}
```

and

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

is translated to this:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "dispatchChannel")
public MessageHandler dispatcherJmsOutboundChannelAdapter() {
     JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = 
                 new JmsSendingMessageHandler(new JmsTemplate(this.connectionFactory));
     handler.setDestinationName("dispatcher.queue");
     return handler;
}
```

Pay attention to this paragraph in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips).

Comment: Thanks Artem. How is the message order translated? Perhaps I missed that.

Comment: M-m-m. You can use `setOrder()` on the `JmsSendingMessageHandler` if I follow you request properly.

Comment: Thanks again. In Gary's solution he has the jms outbound-channel-adapter with order="1" and the service-activator to delete files with order="2"

Comment: OK. That what I mean with `setOrder()`

Comment: This raises an interesting question - we can't apply `order` to the `POJO` style service activator (`removeFile`) - any unordered handlers will be run after **all** ordered handlers. So, if we wanted to run the POJO handler before JMS, it wouldn't work. One workaround would be to to use the `@Bean` style with a `ServiceActivatingHandler` (which **is** `Orderable`). Another would be to rely on declaration order (which I am not keen on).

Comment: Gary, that works with `@Order`. I have just found that logic in the `AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor` and see `SubscriberOrderTests`.

Comment: Thank you! I've added @Order(1) and @Order(2) respectively

Answer (score 0):

The last piece of jigsaw puzzle is FileWritingMessageHandler

```
@Bean
public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("headers.file_originalFile.delete()");
    FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(expression);
    fileWritingMessageHandler.setOutputChannel(new NullChannel());
    fileWritingMessageHandler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    return fileWritingMessageHandler;
}
```

Comment: Please, take a look into my answer. Even if your solution works, it doesn't matter that we have to overhead simple file delete operation with such a monster :-).

Comment: Thanks for providing simpler solution. Just enjoying learning process, monsters will appear from time to time :)